# Kill a stalled Safari Window or Tab?

Tags: macos, script, safari, osx-leopard

Spinning wheel of death too often. I've tried the usual tricks (delete Plist, shut off extensions, reset, uncheck proxy settings, and whatnot).

I don't want to keep shutting down Safari, just the window, or the script or whatever the thing is trying to do.

Seems possible in other platforms. Is there a 3rd party utility for this?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand anything , everything looks like a novel

Comment: Fixed the tags for you.

Comment: Are you running ClickToFlash? If not, try and see if that helps. PPC or Intel?

Comment: Make sure you're on Safari 5.0.2. 5.0.0 was bad news with extensions. 5.0.1 was better, but 5.0.2 is the latest and there's no reason not to go to it. Also consider running Activity Monitor's "Sample" feature, or even Safari's debug menu tools, to figure out what's going wrong in Safari.